# Spark dataframe case when

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm learning spark with scala. I'm trying to publish some values into columns using kind of case statement. Any help would be appreciated.

In input DF I have columns customer, order, type, message, message1, message2. message1 & message2 will always null in input DF. I want to publish message in message1 when type is 'V' and publish message in message 2 when type is 'A'. In the output DF I should have only one record for a customer.

```
DF1: 
cust, order, type, message, message1, message2
c1, o1, V, Verified, null, null
c1, o1, A, Approved, null, null
c2, o2, A, Approved, null, null
c3, o3, V, Verified, null, null

outputDF:
cust, order, type, message, message1, message2
c1, o1, A, Approved, Verified, Approved
c2, o2, A, Approved, null, Approved
c3, o3, V, Verified, Verified, null
```

Comment: You can use [`when/otherwise`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@when(condition:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,value:Any):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) (see example in the link).

Answer (score 1):

If `message1` and `message2` are just nulls, I would just create new columns using [when/otherwise](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark-case-when-otherwise-example/). If `message1` and `message2` do contain other values and you want to retain them, you modify the below example a bit and use existing `message1` and `message2` columns in the `otherwise` parameter.

```
  import spark.implicits._
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.when
  val inputDF = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
    ("c1", "o1", "V", "Verified", "null", "null"),
    ("c1", "o1", "A", "Approved", "null", "null"),
    ("c2", "o2", "A", "Approved", "null", "null"),
    ("c3", "o3", "V", "Verified", "null", "null")
  )).toDF("customer", "order", "type", "message", "message1", "message2")

  val newInputDF = inputDF.select("customer", "order", "type", "message")
  val outputDF = newInputDF
    .withColumn("message1", when($"type" === "V", $"message").otherwise("null"))
    .withColumn("message2", when($"type" === "A", $"message").otherwise("null"))
  outputDF.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in other answers you can use when/otherwise clause for inserting message1 and message2 value based on type. But to satisfy last condition ie, only one row per customer you can do something like below:

```
val df = Seq(("c1", "o1", "V", "Verified", null, null),("c1", "o1", "A", "Approved", null, null), ("c2", "o2", "A", "Approved", null, null), ("c3", "o3", "V", "Verified", null, null)).toDF("cust", "order", "type", "message", "message1", "message2")

val outputDf = df.groupBy($"cust",$"order").agg(collect_list($"type").alias("type"),collect_list($"message").alias("message")).withColumn("message1", when(size($"type")===2,"Verified").when($"type"(0)==="V",$"message"(0))).withColumn("message2", when(size($"type")===2,"Approved").when($"type"(0)==="A",$"message"(0))).withColumn("message", when(size($"type")===2,lit("Approved")).otherwise($"message"(0))).withColumn("type",when(size($"type")===2,"A").otherwise($"type"(0)))

outputDf.show
```

which gives below output:

```
+----+-----+----+--------+--------+--------+
|cust|order|type| message|message1|message2|
+----+-----+----+--------+--------+--------+
|  c2|   o2|   A|Approved|    null|Approved|
|  c1|   o1|   A|Approved|Verified|Approved|
|  c3|   o3|   V|Verified|Verified|    null|
+----+-----+----+--------+--------+--------+
```